# Linear Transformation of a Polynomial

Tags: linear-transformations

I have an operation that takes $ax^2+bx+c$ to $cx^2+bx+a$. I need to find if this corresponds to a linear transformation from $R^3$ to $R^3$, and if so, its matrix.

I know that

$$
ax^2+bx+c = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x^2\\x\\1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

If I perform the column operation $C_1 \leftrightarrow C_3$, then I can get the desired result. However, this would mean putting the corresponding elementary matrix to the right of my coefficient matrix like so:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x^2\\x\\1 \end{bmatrix} = cx^2+bx+a
$$

Is this the answer? I have difficulty accepting that the matrix can simply be put in the middle.

Comment: You should represent each polynomial by a vector. If you take $\{x^2, x, 1\}$ as a basis, then $ax^2 + bx + c$ corresponds to $[a\ b\ c]^T$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Now how would the linear transformation be represented? You should get a matrix.

Comment: I'm still rather confused. I'm self-studying and I don't really have a functional knowledge of basis and spaces.

Comment: Okay. You will probably encounter them later in your studies, and they are pretty important in linear algebra. For now, I guess you only need to know that the polynomials of degree $2$ can be put into a correspondence with $\mathbb R^3$ in the way I suggested. From there, try to think about what the linear transformation $ax^2 + b x + c \mapsto c x^2 + bx + a$ corresponds to when mapping $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you've made sends $x^2+x+1$ to $cx^2+bx+a$ . Also the transformation should be $\mathbb{R}[x]^{3}\to\mathbb{R}[x]^3$ and not $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 0):

$$T((ax^2+bx+c)+(a'x^2+b'x+c'))=T((a+a')x^2+(b+b')x+(c+c'))
\\=(c+c')x^2+(b+b')x+(a+a')
\\=(cx^2+bx+a)+(c'x^2+b'x+a')
\\=T(ax^2+bx+c)+T(a'x^2+b'x+c')$$ and linearity is confirmed.